# How to mock IOException for CharSource.read()?

Tags: java, exception, junit, mockito, ioexception

here is the code for which I want to write a test case for catch block

```
public class X {

protected String getInputString(final String inputPath) {
        try {
            return Resources.asCharSource(Resources.getResource(inputPath), UTF_8).read();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            log.error("Error loading partner aliases from local config", e);
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

have tried mocking the staic method asCharSource as bellow:

```
@Test
    public void Failed() throws Exception{
        URL url = Resources.getResource("resources/linearPartners.json");
        CharSource s;
        try{
            s = new CharSource() {
                @Override
                public Reader openStream() throws IOException {
                    throw new IOException("Expected as a test");
                }

                @Override
                public String read() throws IOException {
                    throw new IOException("Expected as a test");
                }
            };
            try (MockedStatic<Resources> resources = Mockito.mockStatic(Resources.class)) {
                resources.when(() -> Resources.asCharSource(url, UTF_8))
                    .thenReturn(s);
                Assertions.assertThrows(UncheckedIOException.class, () -> staticConfigPartnerAliasesPersistenceFacade.getInputString("resources/file.json"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

bellow is the error

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Unexpected exception type thrown ==> expected: <java.io.UncheckedIOException> but was: <java.lang.NullPointerException>
     [java]        org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:65)
     [java]        org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:37)
     [java]        org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows(Assertions.java:3082)
```

I did not understand, where is the NullPointerException is coming from. Please guide me on this

Comment: Try to call the tested method without wrapping it with `assertThrows`, the stack strace should be more helpful.

Comment: Where do you define `staticConfigPartnerAliasesPersistenceFacade`?

Comment: And personally I would just wrap the `Resources` class in a bean instead of messing about with mocking static methods.